# Why is right-click event slower than left?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm noticing a difference between the execution speeds of a script running on left (onclick=function()) versus right-click (oncontextmenu='function();return false;'). Does anyone know if this is common and if I can make the right-click execution speed just as fast?

I've looked around but haven't really found an answer to this. Appreciate I may have missed it. Let me know if more info necessary - I'm new to this.

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Per my understanding, right click usually provide context options To be fetched From OS and displayed and left click do not have anything to do apart from clicking so right click takes More time to execute.

Comment: Thanks Vivek. That seems like it would slow it down. It'd be nice if it were possible to stop it (the right-click trigger) from trying to fetch from os (assuming that the 'return false' prevents the display but not the fetch) and so presumably achieve an equivalent execution speed to left-click triggered code. But perhaps that's just beyond js.

Comment: Yes. That's correct scon. Also even if we are able to override the right click trigger then it would trigger some functionality (displaying customized menu e.g. in google sheets) and would be slower than left click in that case also.